# PHP isset to check in one step if both array and key are defined

Tags: php, arrays, isset

`$foo` may be **not** defined

```
if( /* condition */ )
{
    $foo = array( 'bar' => 1 );
}
```

later in the code I want to check if both `$foo` is defined and if it has a key named `bar` (holding a non `null` value)

Can I do it in just a single step?

Is this usage of `isset` valid?

```
$defined = isset( $foo['bar'] );
```

---

I tried the above statement in a test script, with `$foo` not defined and no error where thrown. However I invoked php from the console in a context where language rule settings are *loose*.

I'm concerned about php language configuration settings may set a more "strict" language mode where the above is illegal and should be done in more steps:

```
$defined = isset( $foo ) && array_key_exists( 'bar', $foo ) && $foo['bar']!==null;
```

Comment: And your question is? *Is this usage of isset valid?* Yes?! question answered?

Comment: if `$defined = isset( $foo['bar'] );` is a valid statement even in php "strict" modes. I edited the question...

Comment: so why we have `array_key_exists` function when all can be done with just `isset` ?

Comment: The manual has a good explanation about this. The `isset` check will fail if the array key's value is `NULL`. That's where `array_key_exists` comes in handy

Comment: @tlenss you're right, I missed the `NULL` case of `isset` (and edited the question). My concern is about using `isset` to check an array key when not only the key but also the array is not defined. The manual doesn't cover that case (afaik). Anyway I made my tests and self-answered. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$defined = isset( $foo['bar'] );
```

is **valid** to check in a single step if all the following conditions are met:

1. `$foo` is defined
2. `$foo` is an array
3. the array has a key named `bar`
4. the value for the key `bar` is not `null`

Comment: `$defined = isset( $foo ) && isset( $foo['bar'] );` --> This is what you want

Comment: isn't it functionally equivalent but longer?

Comment: It really is. Disregard the comment. I wasn't aware that PHP checks if the variable exists and then the key in the array. You can mark the comments as obsolete.